# CSS div table styling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to style a div table using css. Here is my sample working code:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="table-row">
            <div class="mycolumn" id="sidebar">
                Sidebar area
            </div>
            <div class="mycolumn" id="content">
                <p>content area</p>
                <p>some more content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#sidebar{
    width: 250px;
    background-color: #eaeff1;
}
.table-row {
    display: table-row;
}
.mycolumn {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 15px;
}
#content {
    background-color:#00eff0;
  /* width:100%; */
}
div {
    outline: 1px solid #3a87ad;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gbovzuqm/

How can I get content area div to cover up all the remaining space at the back? I have tried by apply `width:100%` to it, but it will squeeze the sidebar area.

How can I do it with CSS styling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no need to use `display:table-row` use this

```
.table-row {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**[updated jsFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/gbovzuqm/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to correct this you can do like this

```
   .table-row {
        display: table; //replace display:table-row;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have set `display: table-cell`, it only makes sense to also set `display: table-row` and `display: table` to its ancestors in order to simulate a table.

[Click here to see updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gbovzuqm/3/)

This question could be purely academic, but just some things to think about in case you're really doing this in a real life production system: why would you want to use `<div>` to simulate tables and cells when you could simply use `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>`?

Also, from the words used inside the cell data, it sounds like you're using `<div>` as a disguise for tables in order to do page layout. PLEASE don't do this in real life. Tables for layout are hated for good reason; disguising them using other HTML tags is an even worse thing to do.